# Generalized distributivity laws for a Boolean algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, index-notation

I *do not want a proof*! I'm just trying to understand the question since it seems false to me. The following is Exercise 7.10 from the Logic of Mathematics by Adamowicz and Zbierski:

> Prove the generalized distributivity laws for Boolean algebras:
>      $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i1}\cdot \cdots \cdot a_{im} =
>    \prod_{j_1,\ldots,j_n=1}^m (a_{1j_1}+\cdots+a_{nj_n})$$
>      and 
>      $$\prod_{i=1}^n (a_{i1}+\cdots + a_{im}) = \sum_{j_1,\ldots,j_n=1}^m a_{1j_1}\cdot \cdots \cdot a_{nj_n}$$
>      for an arbitrary matrix $\{a_{ij}: i=1,\ldots, n,j=1,\ldots,m\}$ of elements of the algebra.

But I do not understand the RHS.  An example... if $a=[a_{11},a_{12};a_{21},a_{22}]$ (the 2x2 matrix) then the LHS of the first centered equation equals $a_{11}a_{12}+a_{21}a_{22}$. However, I do not know how to start with the RHS. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right-hand side just means a simultaneous product (or sum in the second case) where each $j_i$ independently ranges from $1$ to $n$.  If you like, the symbol $$\prod_{j_1,\ldots,j_n=1}^m$$ means the same thing as an iterated product $$\prod_{j_1=1}^m\prod_{j_2=1}^m\dots\prod_{j_n=1}^m.$$

So for instance, when $n=m=2$, you get $(a_{11}+a_{21})(a_{11}+a_{22})(a_{12}+a_{21})(a_{12}+a_{22})$.

This should look more familiar in the case of the second distributive law, which is just the usual generalized distributive law for multiplication over addition (which holds in any ring, for instance).  For instance, when $n=m=2$, it just says $$(a_{11}+a_{12})(a_{21}+a_{22})=a_{11}a_{21}+a_{11}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}+a_{12}a_{22}.$$  The first distributive law is just the same thing with the roles of addition and multiplication swapped.

Comment: How then can I reconcile my concern: If $a=[\emptyset, \{b,-b\}; b,-b]$ then the LHS seems to just be $\emptyset$ while the RHS is $b$.  Or did I make a mistake in my computation?

Comment: How did you get that the RHS is $b$?

Comment: So we agree that the LHS is $a_{11}a_{12}+a_{21}a_{22}$ and the RHS is $a_{11}a_{21}+a_{11}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}+a_{12}a_{22}$, right? Now let $X$ be the two element BA, let $a_{11}=0$, let $a_{12}=1$ (or $X$), let $a_{21}=b$ and let $a_{22}=-b$ then $a_{11}a_{12}+a_{21}a_{22} = 0\cdot 1+b\cdot(-b) = 0+0=0$ while $a_{11}a_{21}+a_{11}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}+a_{12}a_{22} = 0\cdot b+0\cdot (-b)+1\cdot b+ 1\cdot (-b) = 0+0+b+(-b) = 1$ sorry not $b$ but the two still don't equal each other.

Comment: I don't see any discussion of the LHS in this answer, but anyway what then is the LHS?

Comment: @Squirtle: You're comparing the LHS of the first distributive law with the RHS of the second distributive law.